# Using a Pi as an EEPROM programmer

Tags: rpi.gpio

I'm making my own 8-bit homebrew computer and the only part left to figure out is how I'm going to program the parallel input EEPROM chip I'll be using (IC number: 28C256). I'd like to ask those with more knowledge of the Pi's gpio capabilities whether or not it would be possible to use all the user-accessible pins (17, maybe more with a port expander) to output address and program data to an EEPROM chip?

P.S. The GPIO library I was going to use was Pi4J

Comment: Did you every get anywhere with this? I know it's a few years later but just found myself in the same position.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't

Comment: Ah well... thinking I might give it a go by sacrificing some of the address lines and just holding them low. I don't need the full capacity at any rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using the Pi's gpios alone (21 available for Rev.2 boards).

You need 15 address bits and 8 data bits plus 2 control signals (at least), so a minimum of 25 gpios.

I suppose you could use an I2C port expander for the address bits and use the Pi's gpios for the data and control signals.

Comment: Do you think the Pi will be able to supply enough current to that many pins at once?

Comment: I never considered that as a problem.  The Pi's 3V3 rail will supply circa 50 mA which should be more than enough for the data and control pins.  If you use an I2C port expander that (and its pins) can be powered from the Pi's 5V rail which can supply much more.

Answer (score 1):

I have an old PCB3b Willem EEPROM programmer.  The parallel port required to program PROMs/EPROMs/EEPROMs requires an ECP-mode parallel port (for bi-directional data transfer) which AFAIK excludes all of the USB-to-Printer devices available which are likely "data-out" only.  Since PCs with a REAL parallel port are becoming more scarce (particularly in my house), I think it might be a doable project to put together a level shifter circuit to convert from the RPi's 3.3V GPIOs to the Willem's 5V bi-directional (though I think the pins are dedicated inputs or outputs) data port.

Once the HW adapter is complete, I've found some open-source Willem software for which I will likely have to write a driver or some type of boilerplate to convert from the parallel port operations into the RPis GPIO bus.  It might be a little slow to bit-bang the GPIOs, but speed is secondary to economy.  With the most recent RPis in the $5-$10 range, that solution will be hard to beat for economy and to breathe new life into some old EPROM chips.

I think this solution would work well for you too.  I'm interested in others' thoughts on this too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 5V device, so if you want to read from it, you'd need to convert the devices output voltages to 3.3V. Even if you don't want to read, you might have to do that.

Secondly, to erase the chip, you need a 12V supply.

Answer (score 0):

@Cudamankev

Do you have a link for the open-source software you found? Willem gave me source for a very old version before that guy made the software closed, but I'd like to start with something newer.

I have several old Win98/ME computers I use for the programmers, but I'm not confident that any of the programs follow any of the manufacturer algorithms and decided I want to implement my own.

RPi won't have enough I/O's for higher capacity devices, so I plan to build my own hardware.  It will be more efficient than the method used by Willem type programmers.

I'm going to forego a GUI and control the program from configuration files.  I think Willem was going to go this route with the USB version he was working before he passed away.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/134212)

Answer (score 0):

I think here's what you'll need to consider:

1. The Raspberry Pi has 17 pins that are readily accessible, as you mentioned. You'll need 25 pins for 8-bit data and 16-bit addresses plus clock lines and chip select. It implies going beyond the GPIO onboard.
2. To get the versatility you require, you can add extra pins using expanders based on SPI or I2C. Just make sure the expander of your choice is supported by the library.

And here are resources that may help you out:
[Pi4J documentation](https://pi4j.com/documentation/)
[28C256 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc0006.pdf)
[One article](https://www.ampheo.com/blog/eeprom-vs-flash-main-differences-between-them.html) that has helped me learn about EEPROM
Example EEPROM projects with Raspberry Pi:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom
https://circuitdigest.com/tags/raspberry-pi